# Nvidia VGA and Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

1. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 amd64 and it used the default settings and vga driver: unknown both screens sere working regardless of the errors of turning the laptop's off then both go off forever!
2. So I tried installing Nvidia driver in both ways,**I. From the additional drivers** current-driver way and **II. The manual**:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo sh Nvidia..._.run
sudo service lightdm start
```

Both had the same results,

```
in system info : Graphics : UNKNOWN , in display settings : one UNKNOWN display is detected "the laptop's" and **cannot detect my other display**
```

What I did is that I modified the display's settings from Nvidia settings as a root in order to save the settings

```
sudo nvidia-settings
LG Display > enabled, res: 1920- 1080, 60hz, left of (separate display options)
Laptop Display > right of
```

Now the external screen can turn it's lights on but not useful at all 
I can't make it the default primary screen nor I can use it as primary
if I disable the laptop's the other turns off along with it

I believe if the **Graphics: unknown** problem is solved then all is  solved 
the system doesn't recognize the driver as if it is on it's own

Nvidia admins said it is a problem of the system not the driver

"it was working properly with Ubuntu 10. 04 with Nvidia manual driver installation"

```
Hardware info:
computer type: laptop, type: ASUS f8sn, CPU 2. 4 core 2 due T8300 santarosa penryn,
vga: Nvidia geforce 9500m gs, motherboard: ASUS, bus: Intel, chipset: Intel, external screen: LG E 2205, DVI connector: DVI-D Single link
```

I posted this after maybe the 15th reformat and reinstall of Ubuntu to fix this problem

Comment: Please try this, I had the same problem with X64 and Nvidia graphic card, and finally got it to work with hardware acceleration and everything: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1904230

Comment: i'll check if it works better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around and i found a satisfying solution somehow ! though i still hate this system's bugs :( ;

> the solution is
>
> 1. to open nvidia settings as the root as i explained above
> 2. then enable the external display and modify its properties and use it as (twin display) not (x separate) *Important*
> 3. make it your own default by checking that option
> 4. apply & save the settings over /etc/X11/xorg.conf
> 5. turn your laptop's screen off and just use the external + restart and enjoy

#

> vulnerabilities :
>
> 1. your vga is working for 2 displays rather than for 1
> 2. you cannot disable the laptop's display from the settings or you will lose sight of > both
> 3. your mouse can go to the other display as an extension even if its lights are off
>      (still considered there)
> 4. Graphics will still be unknown in the system thus you can't use the display settings > from the system which means no rotation and no default settings on the system (likebooting up with one specific display on)

if there is a better solution please fill us in..

regards,,

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution to this problem

it is to switch back to ubuntu 10.04 the most stable version ever

now the desktop is working perfectly even with nvidia driver and settings
because the system detects another manager for the display and prioritized the nvidia x settings over the os default display settings .

after you install nvidia driver, and open display settings, a prompt window will appear asking if you want to use nvidia settings or the os settings unlike 11.X which doesn't even know about the existence of another manager (nvidia x settings).

*of course to save the settings u will need to use the root permission

regards,